# How to design a web application (community site) from scratch?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I am running a small *online-community*. It's all self coded and not a common CMS... After a few years I learned a lot and had to realize that I made many mistakes in the beginnings. Thats why I am planning a relaunch of the whole project, hoping to learn even more but also hoping to port most of code and the database.

**That's why my questions came up:**

- What are the most necessary things to think about when planning a website like that?
- Are there design-patterns or structures I should use?
- Is there a good book, like a *bible for website-design*?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out excellent tutorial: - [Web App from Scratch](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebAppFromScratch/) Or this video: - [Building a Website](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/71-building-a-website-photoshop-mockup/)

Comment: money & time - if u dun have budget then migrate to facebook, dun have time then use any open-source CMS/Forum

Comment: I have enough time and manpower to handle it. It's not such a huge project but to individual that facebook can not be a replacement. Tailoring a CMS/Forum to our wishes is almost as time-consuming as doing it on our own.

Comment: in this case, adapt a proper framework ? there are tons of framework available, is up to u for comparison, (i not saying u have to adapt framework just for the sake of having framework). Since u have time, download some of them and installed, try it out, or even code a simple 'Hello world' apps, and after attempts,u probably have a feeling whether to use a framework or not, just my 2cents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure whether you are after the frontend design or the backend design, but anyway:

> What are the most necessary things to think about when planning a website like that?

In a nutshell:

- What is the aim of my website? Can I quantify?
- What architecture best supports my aims?
- Who will visit the site? How often? What for?
- How to optimize for that?

Once you answered these for the first time, answer them again with the knowledge gained by the first time you answered them. In other words: reflect and correct.

> Are there design-patterns or structures I should use?

Back End:

- [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (POEAA)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html)
- [Gang of Four (GOF) Patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)
- [Practical PHP Patterns](http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns)

Front End:

- [Patterns in Information Architecture](http://uidesignpatterns.org/designPatterns)
- [Interaction Design Patterns](http://www.welie.com/patterns/)

> Is there a good book, like a bible for website-design?

Have a look around SO. I am pretty sure this has been asked and answered before. For software architectural patterns, there is books for the aforementioned POEAA and GOF patterns, explaining them in detail. They are pretty much the Bibles of Software Design Patterns.

Comment: Yes, indeed very helpful links! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about web deseign, this is the wrong place, as Stack Overflow is for programmers, not designers.

For website development in PHP, this video is really useful, and shows how to run your website along with a database. http://www.tactools.org/php-video-tutorials-database-website-from-scratch.html

Comment: no, it's not about the graphical design of the UI, but about the design of the code and structure.

Comment: I'm glad that's what you meant, too often website design means the same as website development to some people.

Comment: If you read the post, its about the architecting/designing the backbone of the web application. Its not about the web page design. I understand that the title might be misleading.